# Mean from multiple Columns (Error Message)

Tags: r, function, dataset, mean

I'm still fairly new to R and have been practicing a bit lately.

I have the following (simplified) Data Set:

[image]

So it's basically a Questionnaire asking random People which of these Cities they prefer from 1-7.

I would like to find out which city has the highest average preference.

So what I first did was: `mean(dataset[, 3], na.rm=TRUE)` to find out the average preference for Prag. That worked!

 Now I wanted to create a table which shows me every mean of each city. 
My thought was: `table(mean(dataset[3:8], na.rm=TRUE))`

However, all I get is the following Error Message:

> In mean.default(umfrage[37:38], na.rm = TRUE) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA**

Does someone know what that means and how I could achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I simply used this function: `lapply(dataset[3:8], mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Note that there is a base R function `colMeans` that executes the fastest: `mymeans <- colMeans(dataset[3:8], na.rm = TRUE)`  There is a collection of Base R row and column basic stat functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dplyr and tidyr package (both packages are integrated in the tidyverse package):

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- dataset %>% 
  gather("city", "value", Pref_Prague:Pref_London) %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value))
```